# Termination of a .net program

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an application which I wrote in vb.net. When the application starts it connects to mysql database online to get some data and once done it proceeds.

The problem is that at times it gets stuck in the mysql thing, I mean after requesting nothing happens and this causes my program to lock up. This can be because of internet problem or server.

Is there a way the program can determine that x seconds has elapsed and it has not got any data, so self terminate it. I tried using timer to perform this action but as the program requests for data, it gets stuck, I mean it locks up and thus timer also locks up and only after task is done everything resumes.

I wanted that when the program is about to start request, I can start a timer and determine that x seconds has elapsed, so now terminate the application.

Please let me know how can I do this ?

Thanks,

Cheers,
Greatchap

Comment: Can't you add a timeout to the mySql connection string? Then that should at least generate an exception in your thread to resume processing.

Comment: Well, if the only recovery option you have is to end the process, you could start another thread that waits on an autoResetEvent with your timeout.  If the database responds, signal the event and, in the thread, if signalled, just exit.  If the autoResetEvent wait times out, call Environment.Exit(1);

Comment: System.Threading.Timer would do.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can as you say, use a Timer and force the app to exit after a certain time has passed. However, it would make a lot more sense it you set a timeout on your MySqlConnection.

`MySqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout` is where you would do this in your case.

If for some reason you must kill it. You can use `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()` for your timer.

Comment: By default mysql connection timeout is set to 15. That seems to be ok but i dont think its working the way it should.

Comment: What went wrong? Did you try to bring it down to a couple of seconds and it doesn't timeout? Not sure what else is locking your application and killing it seems rather drastic.

Comment: The problem is timer does not work once thru threading. Plus app locks up while mysql is working so timer isnt helping.

Comment: Set your timer like this:
Timer timer = new Timer(x => Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill(), null, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2), TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
This is C# but VB would be something like "Dim timer as Timer = ". Been too long since I did VB.

Comment: I know how to insert and use timer in vb.net. But the problem is when my program is firing the mysql command, the app locks up and timer does not function. Only after the mysql process is complete that timer resumes.

Comment: I think I solved the problem by using system.timers.timer. :) This timer does not stop even if your app has locked up.

Comment: What timer did you use before?

Comment: Ok, should have been more specific. I use the System.Threading timer.